# Passing data from a dynamic table to a static table

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, delegates

I'm a newbie in IOS, 
I've been strugling with passing data from child to parent tableview. I have defined the parent table view as static, four cells are connected to other table views. These tableviews has data i would like when selected to be passed to my static cell accordingly. I read a lot of solutions about passing data, using delegates and segue but none of them seem to be working for me. i.e. a repeat cell in static table view has two labels and the `UILabel` Repeat, I don't want that to change and repeatDetail this is the one that when a disclosure indicator is triggered and a new tableview is presented with the data to choose to be able when i click back button to have the seleted data in my repeatDetail Label. My static table is embeded in Navigation controller using storyboard. I would like when data is selected in `FirstChildViewController` to modify selected data i.e. Monday to Mon in RootViewController. However in my code after selecing data in child checkmark is there but as soon 
as I move back to RootVC nothing is showing,and when i go back to Child no selction is howing either.
1. Save the selected Data in Child, only change when there is new selection
2. Use short week names when sending to RootVC
3. repeatDetail to have the selected data
 Without writting too much let me show what i have done.

```
in RootViewController.h // RootViewController is static
#import "FirstChildViewController"

@interface RootViewController: UITableViewController <repeatProtocol> //RootViewController COnfirms to the delegate

@property repeat, repeatDetail;

@end


next on my RootViewController.m

@implementaion RootViewController
@sysnthesis repeat,repeatDetail;


- (void) viewDidload
{
repeat.text = @"Repeat"
repeatDetail= //not show how call this label from 1stViewController

}

-(void) selectedValue:(NSString *)string  //protocol method
{ 
    FirstChildViewController *RVC =[[FirstChildViewController alloc] init];
    RVC.delegate =self;
    [self selectedValue:string];  //This part confuses me, i know i have to implement the delegate method but not sure if i implement it correctly.
}

-(void) didReceiveMemoryWarning
{ 
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 

}



in FirstChildViewController.h

@class FirstChildViewController
@protocol repeatProtocol <NSObject>
@required 
-(void) selectedValue:(NSString *)string;
@end
@interface FirstChildViewController: UITableViewController
{
NSArray *tableData;
id <repeatProtocol > repeatDelegate;
NSString *selectedDay;

}
@property (retain) id <repeatProtocol> repeatDelegate;


in FirstChildViewController.m

@synthesize tableData;
@synthesize repeatDelegate;

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad]
tableData= [NSArray alloc] initWithArrays:@"Sunday",@"Monday",@"Tuesday",@"Wednesday",@"Thursday",@"Friday",@"Saturday";

}

- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 7;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RepeatCell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"RepeatCell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]//strings from an array here;    
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = {tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessaryType = UITableViewCellAccessaryCheckMark;
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(selectedValue:)])
    {
        [self.myDelegate selectedValue:selectedDay];
        NSLog(@"string passed");
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"FirstChildViewController dismissed");

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to sort out what's happening from your description; so I'll restate what I think the issue is.

You have a `UITableView` that displays something like settings that you which to modify in a series of distal view controllers.  But you're unsure of what mechanism to use when returning that data to the static table view.  Basically, you want to capture that data when the distal controller finishes.  I won't deal with how you're displaying it in the root view controller, because it's unclear from your code sample.

Nonetheless, I'd favor not using a formal delegate protocol at all.  It's just one datum going back - so a protocol seems like a wasted formality.  I'd use a completion block.

So your `FirstViewController` interface could look like

```
typedef void(^WeekdayCompletionBlock)(NSString *dayName);

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) WeekdayCompletionBlock completionBlock;

@end
```

When you instantiate your `FirstViewController`, just provide it with a completion block.  Since I *think* you are using Storyboards, you'd do this in `prepareForSegue:` method of your `RootViewController`.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *destinationController = segue.destinationViewController;
    if( [destinationController isKindOfClass:[FirstViewController class]] ) {
        [(FirstViewController *)destinationController setCompletionBlock:^(NSString *returnString){
            //  do something here with your string
            //  maybe you must reload your table
            //  it depends on where your returning data needs to display
        }];
    }
}
```

Finally, you need to execute that block when the user passes control back to the `RootViewController`.  For example, is there a *Save* button or the like?  There you would just execute the completion block, e.g. `self.completionBlock(myNewDayOfWeekString)`

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear on my question. My rootviewcontroller is like Settings, created segue from Repeat Cell to the next tableview where tableData is displayed and selected. I'm able to make selection using checkMark. After selection I want the selected tableData to be passed back to my rootVC. In rootVC I woud like to show it in repeatDetail.text as shortWeekDaySymbol. My issue after selection when going back to rootVC no data is showing under repeatDetail.

Comment: Great - that's how I understood it.  Then you should be able to follow the suggestions about for a workable solution.  (In your case, you would execute something like `repeatDetail.text = returnString` inside the completion block.

Comment: thanx so much NSBUm for the quick response, i'm still a bit confused with the self.completioBlock(myNewDayOfWeekString), since the save button is in FirstVC, where do i implement it FirstVC or RootVC.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can create a global NSString in rootVC.h:

```
NSString *returnString;
```

Include rootVC.h in firstVC.h if you haven't already done that. This allows returnString to be accessible from firstVC.m:

```
#import "rootVC.h"
```

You can assign returnString in firstVC.m:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    returnString = <selected value>;

}
```

And show the returnString in rootVC.m below as NSBum pointed out:

```
-(void) viewDidload
{
    repeat.text = @"Repeat";
    repeatDetail.text = returnString;
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry but still not working. i have made all you suggestion, but still getting an error.- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSLog (@"The selected day/s is %@", [completionBlock objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
} is my did select method in FirstVC.

Comment: also my my return string returnString = completionBlock; returns "returnString not declared" and yet i have imported RootVC to FirstVC.h

Comment: Can you copy the .h file where you declared returnString?  Make sure it's declared outside of @interface to make the variable global.